# install Django in python 2.7

Tags: python, django, macos, python-2.7

I have mac os 10.6.8 and I decide to install django on my mac with python version 2.7 django installed successfully using sudo pip install Django==1.6.1 but when type import django in python shell it prints:

```
     Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
     ImportError: No module named django
```

but when I type pip freeze in terminal it prints Django==1.6.1 and it shows django is installed but what should I do to place django in python and when use import django it prints it's version and enable me to start work with it?

Comment: Check the output of `which python` and `which pip`. Lots of times the above issue is because your pip is operating on a python environment different from what the default python app in your command line is using.

Comment: I did but can't understand if there is problem, so pased the terminal result: Tinas-MacBook-Pro:~ tina$ which pip
/usr/local/bin/pip
Tinas-MacBook-Pro:~ tina$ which python
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python

Comment: K so the python command you are running is the system python while pip is installed via some other means, brew or macports maybe?

Comment: Why aren't you using virtualenv?

Comment: Is there a python command in /usr/local/bin? also I would recommend `virtualenv` as well

Comment: I don't need virtualenv because I dont want to have different version of python I think I should remove old version of python.

Comment: I don't recommend removing the old version of python. That was installed as part of your mac os installation and software that relies on it may expect it to be a certain version.

Comment: I went to /usr/local/bin and there was python 2.7 and 3.3 and none of them had django! :(

Comment: run `pip show django`. Maybe the path its installed will help figure out which python. When you were in `/usr/local/bin` did you run `./python2.7` or just python2.7

Comment: yes! it is installed for python 2.6 in Location: /Library/Python/2.6/site-packages
tnx :)